# Modifying array in redux store

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I am working on a web app built on react + redux + thunk.

I have action creators as below. There are 2 async API calls, first fetchUser() will get user related info from the server, then fetchUserComments is another async call which returns me all the user comments.

```
export function fetchUserInfoFlow () {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(fetchUser()).then(() => {
       return dispatch(fetchUserComments()
    })
  }
}

export function fetchUser() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return axios.get('urlhere')
      .then(function (response) {
      // basically fetch user data and update the store
      dispatch({type: FETCH_USERS, user:response.data)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error)
      })
  }
}

export function fetchUserComment() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return axios.get('urlhere')
      .then(function (response) {

      // fetch user comments, get the user list from store, matching the user id and append the comments list to the user

      let user = {...getState().user}
      response.data.forEach(function (userComment) {
        user.forEach(function (userComment) {
           if(user.userId = userComment.userId){
                user.comments = userComment.comments
            }
        }
      }
      dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_COMMENT, user:response.data)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error)
      })
  }
}
```

I have several action creators similar to the above fetching user's related info and finally updating modifying the store's user list.

The problem is that the component does not re-render when the state updated, suspect if I have mutated the user list somewhere.

And I have read several articles that using getSate() in action creator should be only used in several cases and should not update its values as this will mutates the state.

In this cases, where should I put the logic of modifying the user list and how to avoid mutating the user list?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This part should just go into your reducer, since thats the only place you should be making changes to the state:

```js
  let user = {...getState().user}
  response.data.forEach(function (userComment) {
    user.forEach(function (userComment) {
       if(user.userId = userComment.userId){
            user.comments = userComment.comments //mutating state
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think it is kind of difficult to decide. Let say if I have to add last successful login to the user array, then possibly I need create new Date() in the reducer. As a result, my reducer becomes non-functional. I will take your advice for now before I have a better solution, thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah so if you want to timestamp the last successful login from the clientside, you can use `redux-saga` (or your write your own middleware) to dispatch another action with new Date() in the payload

Comment: Get the idea. Appreciated your help, will have a try.

Comment: No prob glad that was helpful